# Is this a correct way change theme programatically via "layout_load_before" event Observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

In need to change themes based on customer group.

after some google I found a hook where I can made a change "layout_load_before". I am not sure this is effective solution or not. 
I mean here.

**Does this will affect theme fallback system of magento2?**

**Does this effect to full page cache system of magento2?**

All I need proper explanation of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safest way to change theme following class and method

**Magento/Theme/Model/Design.php**

```
public function loadChange($storeId, $date = null)
```

Dynamic design change should be (for example)

```
$this->setData([
    'store_id' => 1,
    'design' => 3 // theme_id from theme table
]);
```

NB: Don't modify core file. Override or Pluginize core class method.

Comment: Thanks for reply soon., as my question is not regarding to how to do  it, it is related does that make issue with cache systme?

Comment: As I said first, It is the safest way :) .

Comment: i already know solution, all i don't know was that cache system of magento2 allow us to create multiple cache for single site or not, and it allows us some how. any why thanks once again.